# how to fix a ul code list in a html and css

Tags: html, css

I need to center an unordered list, and add a text header and a footer while still keeping the list-items left aligned.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #ccc;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  ul {
    transform: scale(0.6);
  }
}

@media (min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 700px) {
  ul {
    transform: scale(0.7);
  }
}

@media (min-width: 701px) and (max-width: 800px) {
  ul {
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

ul li {
  margin: 0 40px;
}

ul li a .fa {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #555;
  line-height: 80px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

ul li a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  transform: perspective(1000px) rotate(-30deg) skew(25deg) translate(0,0);
  transition: 0.5s;
  box-shadow: -20px 20px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

ul li a::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: -20px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20px;
  background: #b2b2b2;
  transition: 0.5s;
  transform: rotate(0deg) skewY(-45deg);
}

ul li a::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
  left: -10px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #e5e5e5;
  transition: 0.5s;
  transform: rotate(0deg) skewX(-45deg);
}

ul li a:hover {
  transform: perspective(1000px) rotate(-30deg) skew(25deg) translate(20px,-20px);
  box-shadow: -50px 50px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

ul li:hover .fa {
  color: #fff;
}

ul li:hover:nth-child(1) a {
  background-color: #3b5999;
}

ul li:hover:nth-child(1) a::before {
  background-color: #2f477a;
}

ul li:hover:nth-child(1) a::after {
  background-color: #4e69a3;
}

ul li:hover:nth-child(2) a {
  background-color: #55acee;
}

ul li:hover:nth-child(2) a::before {
  background-color: #4489be;
}

ul li:hover:nth-child(2) a::after {
  background-color: #66b4ef;
}

ul li:hover:nth-child(3) a {
  background-color: #dd4b39;
}

ul li:hover:nth-child(3) a::before {
  background-color: #b03c2d;
}

ul li:hover:nth-child(3) a::after {
  background-color: #e05d4c;
}

ul li:hover:nth-child(4) a {
  background-color: #0077b5;
}

ul li:hover:nth-child(4) a::before {
  background-color: #005f90;
}

ul li:hover:nth-child(4) a::after {
  background-color: #1984bc;
}

ul li:hover:nth-child(5) a {
  background-color: #e4405f;
}

ul li:hover:nth-child(5) a::before {
  background-color: #b6334c;
}

ul li:hover:nth-child(5) a::after {
  background-color: #e6536f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/9e3f22ff10.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

when i added a header or  or  the text is written on the left side of the icons and cannot be moved on top or center i have entered them in an html tag and body tag also didn't work

Comment: So you want to center the text but not the icons?

Comment: Uh, that markup is not valid - is that what you're actually trying to use, or just what you put together for the Stick Snippet?

Comment: @HackerFrosch yes ur right

Comment: @HackerFrosch i want to add a text and center it above the icons

Answer (score 0):

Add `p` elements before and after the `ul` element and then style them with css:

```css
body {
  background: #ccc;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  gap: 50px;
}

p {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Here‘s a fully working example

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #ccc;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  gap: 50px;
}

p {
    text-align: center;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  ul {
    transform: scale(0.6);
  }
}

@media (min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 700px) {
  ul {
    transform: scale(0.7);
  }
}

@media (min-width: 701px) and (max-width: 800px) {
  ul {
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

ul li {
  margin: 0 40px;
}

ul li a .fa {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #555;
  line-height: 80px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

ul li a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  transform: perspective(1000px) rotate(-30deg) skew(25deg) translate(0,0);
  transition: 0.5s;
  box-shadow: -20px 20px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

ul li a::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: -20px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20px;
  background: #b2b2b2;
  transition: 0.5s;
  transform: rotate(0deg) skewY(-45deg);
}

ul li a::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
  left: -10px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #e5e5e5;
  transition: 0.5s;
  transform: rotate(0deg) skewX(-45deg);
}

ul li a:hover {
  transform: perspective(1000px) rotate(-30deg) skew(25deg) translate(20px,-20px);
  box-shadow: -50px 50px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

ul li:hover .fa {
  color: #fff;
}

ul li:hover:nth-child(1) a {
  background-color: #3b5999;
}

ul li:hover:nth-child(1) a::before {
  background-color: #2f477a;
}

ul li:hover:nth-child(1) a::after {
  background-color: #4e69a3;
}

ul li:hover:nth-child(2) a {
  background-color: #55acee;
}

ul li:hover:nth-child(2) a::before {
  background-color: #4489be;
}

ul li:hover:nth-child(2) a::after {
  background-color: #66b4ef;
}

ul li:hover:nth-child(3) a {
  background-color: #dd4b39;
}

ul li:hover:nth-child(3) a::before {
  background-color: #b03c2d;
}

ul li:hover:nth-child(3) a::after {
  background-color: #e05d4c;
}

ul li:hover:nth-child(4) a {
  background-color: #0077b5;
}

ul li:hover:nth-child(4) a::before {
  background-color: #005f90;
}

ul li:hover:nth-child(4) a::after {
  background-color: #1984bc;
}

ul li:hover:nth-child(5) a {
  background-color: #e4405f;
}

ul li:hover:nth-child(5) a::before {
  background-color: #b6334c;
}

ul li:hover:nth-child(5) a::after {
  background-color: #e6536f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/9e3f22ff10.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul>
    <li>
        <p>Facebook</p>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    <li>
        <p>Twitter</p>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    <li>
        <p>Google</p>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    <li>
        <p>LinkedIn</p>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    <li>
        <p>Instagram</p>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what i meant i want to put a text above the icons in the middle of the page Social Media Accounts thats the text not above every icon

Comment: @Roka Oh well I edited my answer. Is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will fix your issue but you have to add some extra css to make it exactly as per your needs

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #ccc;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  ul {
    transform: scale(0.6);
  }
}

@media (min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 700px) {
  ul {
    transform: scale(0.7);
  }
}

@media (min-width: 701px) and (max-width: 800px) {
  ul {
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  
}

ul li {
  margin: 0 40px;
  position: relative;
}

ul li p {
     position: absolute;
    top: -8px;
    left: -8px;
    z-index: 10;
    transform: rotate(-33deg);
}

ul li a .fa {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #555;
  line-height: 80px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

ul li a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  transform: perspective(1000px) rotate(-30deg) skew(25deg) translate(0,0);
  transition: 0.5s;
  box-shadow: -20px 20px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

ul li a::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: -20px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20px;
  background: #b2b2b2;
  transition: 0.5s;
  transform: rotate(0deg) skewY(-45deg);
}

ul li a::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
  left: -10px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #e5e5e5;
  transition: 0.5s;
  transform: rotate(0deg) skewX(-45deg);
}

ul li a:hover {
  transform: perspective(1000px) rotate(-30deg) skew(25deg) translate(20px,-20px);
  box-shadow: -50px 50px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

ul li:hover .fa {
  color: #fff;
}

ul li:hover:nth-child(1) a {
  background-color: #3b5999;
}

ul li:hover:nth-child(1) a::before {
  background-color: #2f477a;
}

ul li:hover:nth-child(1) a::after {
  background-color: #4e69a3;
}

ul li:hover:nth-child(2) a {
  background-color: #55acee;
}

ul li:hover:nth-child(2) a::before {
  background-color: #4489be;
}

ul li:hover:nth-child(2) a::after {
  background-color: #66b4ef;
}

ul li:hover:nth-child(3) a {
  background-color: #dd4b39;
}

ul li:hover:nth-child(3) a::before {
  background-color: #b03c2d;
}

ul li:hover:nth-child(3) a::after {
  background-color: #e05d4c;
}

ul li:hover:nth-child(4) a {
  background-color: #0077b5;
}

ul li:hover:nth-child(4) a::before {
  background-color: #005f90;
}

ul li:hover:nth-child(4) a::after {
  background-color: #1984bc;
}

ul li:hover:nth-child(5) a {
  background-color: #e4405f;
}

ul li:hover:nth-child(5) a::before {
  background-color: #b6334c;
}

ul li:hover:nth-child(5) a::after {
  background-color: #e6536f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/9e3f22ff10.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul>
  <li>
  <p>facebook</p>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
  <li>
  <p>twitter</p>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
  <li>
  <p>google</p>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
  <li>
  <p>linkedin</p>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
  <li>
  <p>instagram</p>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Wow you just compied my answer

Comment: lol grow up man I didn't even see your answer